# Should I use different reCAPTCHA key for each instance of it?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm currently implementing Google's reCAPTCHA V2 into my website. I have already gotten one example to work in my website.

Now I want to put it also in some other places (On different templates). However, before I do it, I must know if I should use different keys for each instance of it?

(My POST query contains 'remoteip' if it does matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you're fine. A different set of keys is needed for each *domain*.